# Surge protector for car USB port

Tags: voltage, usb, automotive, surge-protection, spike

OK so the car manual says not to stick items into the car's USB port while starting the car. Like any good engineer(ing student) I tried to see what will happen if I did so, and am now the proud owner of a few dead USB sticks. So yes, the manual wasn't kidding.

Without going through the hassle of sticking an oscilloscope into the USB car ports, I presume that some kind of voltage spike must be going through the USB port when the car engine is started. What causes it? The current surge in the starter motor circuit causing an inductive current pulse in adjacent wiring from the 12V battery to the USB port?

It is somewhat tedious to remember to remove items from the USB port before starting the car, so I was wondering if we could design some kind of surge protector for the USB port to prevent it frying sensitive electronics.

Any comments on my attached circuit diagram? What capacitances and inductances would you suggest, absent any tests with an oscilloscope to quantify the surge size and times? (It is OK to over-engineer it)

[image: Circuit sketch]

Would you also recommend similarly protecting the data in/out ports of the USB output, just in case?

Regarding the question about the car model, see a similar warning from a Youtube video on another model of car. [Kia USB port video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lJ80xtO7Ho)

[image: USB port warning]

Comment: Maybe add a ferrite bead in series, and I would throw in a 5.1V zener. Any other ideas? Can't say anything about datalines, but they probably depend on vcc, so vcc protection is probably enough. But then again, I'm not the one to know it for sure

Comment: **car manual says not to stick items into the car's USB port while starting the car** is a design cop-out. It should be ok to start the car with the USB in _or_ there should be a device that spits out the USB when starting _or_ the car won't start with the USB in place. This is an administrative solution where an engineering solution is required. What kind of car is this so I may avoid purchasing one?

Comment: That may be specific to that model car, maybe even to that year, rather than a general problem.

Comment: I would try a few zener diodes in parallel

Comment: A single Zener, even one with higher power than usual,  won't have enough power so more than one are required. Maybe 5 or 6. Then TVS Diode on the data pins. There are TVS diodes designed for USB. You can put TVS diodes on the power line too, but zener are much cheaper and as fast, and you need them in the same number.

Answer (score 1):

If "car manual" says so about USB sticks, it is a very poor design. USB ports are fed from 5 V supply, which should be generated from inside of USB-enabled equipment. 12 v to 5 V should provide enough margin to have a stable +5V with a little engineering effort. So making a L-C filter makes no sense.

The problem is likely in the fact that 12V rail fluctuates wildly when cranking the car engine. Here is the [cold-crank waveform](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva741/snva741.pdf?ts=1591769909975) as assumed by ISO 7637-2 standard

[image]

So it is expected that the supply voltage drops down to 3V level and stays at 50% level for up to 20 seconds. It is difficult (costly) to maintain an audio/USB/on-board computer equipment to sustain such deep and long drops. So in most cars (and especially inexpensive ones) the equipment simply is turned off during cold cranking. The problem with USB is likely that "surprise disconnect" of USB host might cause device corruption if there is no sufficient power hold and graceful system shutdown and recovery. A L-C filter of any reasonable size cannot help here. The problem can be solved by having a small secondary (backup) battery that is capable of maintaining quality power to USB-related equipment just for 20-30 seconds, a small local UPS so to speak.

Comment: It's possible that voltage drops to 3 or 6V then jump suddenly above 12V. And the isolated power supply can't adapt fast enough.

Comment: OK thanks, I learnt something new regarding the voltage drop during start-up. So as I understand it the problem is probably not a voltage spike killing the USB drive, but a corrupted filesystem from a sudden voltage drop during engine start-up?

What battery would you recommend for keeping in a car? The maximum operating temperature of lithium batteries is 55C and car interiors can reportedly reach up to 68C in the summer. I've always been worried about having batteries in the car - even have a camping icebox for keeping my laptop inside if I know I will be leaving it in the car, in the sun.

Comment: @Fredled, there are plenty of DC-DC converters that are capable to withstand 40-60V input range. Usually operating at  200-kHz- 1.5 MHz switching rate, they are more than fast enough to react to 5 ms edges, as the standard cold-crank waveform implies. More, it is easy to put a simple surge protector >12V at input end of the power supply and forget the problem. Or the same C-L-C filter as in the op question.

Comment: @MeEngineerTrustMe, there are small lead-acid sealed batteries on the market. All you need is a 150 mA-h battery to hold 5 A for 100 seconds. Also, there are Li-ion cells with -40+150C range. https://www.customcells.org/products-development/high-temperature-cell-technology/  Tesla/Toyota are also cars, and operate under the same sunny environment.

Comment: @Ale..chenski The reaction time is not related to switching rate but by the time it takes for the output voltage to be sensed back and a new frequency being applied. It's never instant. If the voltage goes from 6V to 18V in a very short but very sharp spike (the example of clod-crank waveform is academical theory) it won;t have the time to react. A few microseconds at twice the max voltage is enough to kill a USB stick after a few times if not immediately.You don't need a millisecond.

Comment: A MOV varistor won't protect very effectively in the range between 12V and 20V. Moreover the problem is not only overvoltage at the input but the fast rise in voltage. (Not visible in the example). TVS diodes would not sustain more than a few engine starts. So it's not that easy. These protections would be more effective at the output of the power supply. Maybe even with a L78 linear voltage regulator or a LDO after the power supply.